# if $F$ is defined as $\int_0^x f$, why isn't awalys true that $F'(x) = f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

for example, $f(x) = 0$ if $x \leq 1, f(x) = 1$ if $x>1$.

at which point $x$ is $F'(x) = f(x)$ ?

The correct answer is All $x \ne 1$.

But since  $F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t) dt = f(x)$, when $x =1$, $f(1) = 0$, and $F'(1) = 0$ as well.

I'm confused that why isn't $F'(x) = f(x)$ since that how we define $F$.

Also, the same question finding which point $x$ is $F'(x) = f(x)$  for

(1) $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational, $f(x) = 1/p$ if $x=q/p$ in lowest term.

(2) $f(x) = 1$ if $x \leq 0$ or $x > 1$, $f(x) = 1/[1/x]$ if $0<x\leq 1$

I don't know how to approach it either, since I definitely misunderstand the definition afterall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)dt=f(x)$ always (also, that's exactly what you want to prove, so you can't use it in your proof!)

In your first example, $F$ is not differentiable at $x=1$. $F$ is only differentiable at $x$ when $f$ is continous at $x$. What is true is that, whenever $f$ is continous at $x$, $F$ will be differentiable at $x$, and the formula $F'(x)=f(x)$ will hold.

As for the last two examples, you need to find the points at which $f$ is continous. For (1), $f$ is continous at the irrationals (since any sequence of rationals $p/q$ that converge to an irrational must satisfy $q\to\infty$, because given any $N$, there are only finitely many rationals $p/q$ in any bounded interval with $q<N$). You can show that $F(x)=0$ for every $x$ in this case. This means that $F$ will be everywhere differentiable, but again, the formula $F'(x)=f(x)$ will hold only at points in which $f$ is continous.

For (2), draw the graph of $f$ to show that $f$ is continous at every point, except $x=0$. As discussed in the comments below, since $f$ has limits $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) \neq \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$, these limits will be the lateral derivatives of $F$, and then $F$ won't be differentiable at $0$.

Comment: but sometimes equality holds even for some function not continuous at x ?

Comment: I don't think so. If $F$ is differentiable at $x$, then $F(x+h) = F(x) + \lambda\cdot h + o(h)$, where $o(h)$ is a function that satisfies $o(h)/h\to 0$ as $h\to 0$, and $\lambda=F'(x)$. This means that $\int_x^h f = \lambda\cdot h + o(h)$. I think you can use this to show that $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h) = \lambda$, so that if $F$ is differentiable at $x$, then $f$ is either continous at $x$, or has a _removable discontinuity_ at $x$, meaning that if we redefine $f(x)=\lambda$, then $f$ will be continous.

Comment: All in all, this means that if $F$ is differentiable at $x$, then we are sure that $F'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)$. Then, if we also have the equality $F'(x)=f(x)$, we will have $f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)$, and hence $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Ok, I'm wrong in these comments. I was assuming that $f$ had lateral limits. When $f$ doesn't have lateral limits, you can find examples in which $F'=f$ but $f$ is discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of calculus (in the usual form stated for undergraduates) requires that $f$ is continuous. That is, **if** $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $F(x) := \int_a^x f(t)dt$, **then** $F'(x) = f(x)$.

If you are working with an $f$ that is not continuous, you have no guarantee that the fundamental theorem of calculus applies, and hence no reason to suspect that $F'(x)=f(x)$.

In your questions you have to more carefully use the definition of derivative.
I'll give you a hint:

(1) $F(x) = 0$ for all $x$, and hence $F'(x) =0$ for all $x$, so $F'(x)=f(x)$ for irrational $x$ only.

Can you solve (2) with a similar method?

Comment: However, those two questions taken from Spivak, he claims that sometimes $F'(x) = f(x)$ even if $f$ is not continuous. and we are supposed to solve and finding such $x$ in the questions I post, so anyway of approaching it?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it just may happen that $F'(x) = f(x)$ even if $f$ is not continuous. However, you have no reason to expect this to be the case.

Comment: so, can I say the trick of dealing questions like this is to find the point $x$ where $F$ differentiable, implies $F'(x)=f(x)$ ?